# Need help in Nexus repo creation

Tags: nexus

I am using Nexus Repository Manager (OSS 3.0.0-03) for repository management. Can someone please help me with Rest API to create the "hosted" repository of "raw" format. I have tried with the following command:

```
repository.xml
<repository>
  <data>
    <id>aem-demo</id>
    <name>aem-demo</name>
    <exposed>true</exposed>
    <repoType>hosted</repoType>
    <repoPolicy>Allow redeploy</repoPolicy>
    <providerRole>org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.Repository</providerRole>
    <format>raw</format>
  </data>
</repository>

Command to create the repository:
curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -f -X POST -v -d "@repository.xml" -u admin:password http://host:8081/nexus/repository

But I am facing following error:
    * About to connect() to IP_ADDRESS port 8081 (#0)
    *   Trying IP_ADDRESS...
    * Connected to IP_ADDRESS (IP_ADDRESS) port 8081 (#0)
    * Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
    > POST /nexus/repository/ HTTP/1.1
    > Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=
    > User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
    > Host: IP_ADDRESS:8081
    > Accept: application/xml
    > Content-Type: application/xml
    > Content-Length: 320
    >
   * upload completely sent off: 320 out of 320 bytes
   * The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
   * Closing connection 0
   curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request


Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 2.x REST API will not work with Nexus 3.  See here:  http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html